# как записать результаты функции match в файл?

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Файл остается пустым после записи в него
в чем моя ошибка?**

```
import re

mytext = open('es_2.txt', encoding="utf8")
lines = mytext.readlines()

validation = open("validation.txt", "a")

textlookfor = open ('cards.txt', encoding="utf8")

for line in lines:
    for r in textlookfor:
        print(r)
        print(lines)
        # if re.match(r, lines):
            # save to ('validation.txt', 'a')
            # validation.write()
            # break
            # validation.close()
```

Comment: Ты же ничего не записываешь в файл, я просто вижу что у тебя метод `write` никакого текста не получает..

Comment: Но ведь Вы никуда не записываете. `print` — функция печати в `stdout` (стандартный поток вывода; если явно не указано иное, то это консоль). И почему строки закомментированы? Поясните, пожалуйста, подробнее, что должна делать Ваша программа. Вы можете это сделать, нажав кнопку [edit].

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы записать текст в файл используйте метод .write - например `validation.write('some text')`